# How do you turn off bluetooth search? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

We have a windows 10 gaming computer, the bluetooth keeps searching for something that is not there we don't even know what it is searching for;  therefore it continues to run in the background. Is there a way to just turn off the bluetooth's searching because we don't use anything wirelessly on it. We can't find anything that even says Bluetooth when we search for a place to turn it off.

Comment: do you use bluetooth for anything on the system? If so we can just disable it, if you are using bluetooth peripherals it would be harder to configure how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Press the start key and begin to type "bluetooth", you will quickly see "Bluetooth Settings" appear - click on this and flip the "on" switch to "off".

This will obviously disable bluetooth, the simplest way to get around your problem, let me know if you run into any issues.